# Google Weather's notifications show weather in F°

Tags: notifications, google, weather

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy A30s. The following is what I see in my notification panel - 70° in Peniche, Portugal

[image: Very hot weather or?]

Clicking in it, I'll get the following screen which has the number for the weather correct

[image: Google weather]

Clicking in the three dots, I can see that the weather is selected to show in Celcius

[image: Weather in Celsius but showing in Fahrenheit in the notifications]

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone to Settings, searched for the term "Weather" and got the following

[image: Google Assistant's weather]

Clicking in it could see that it was defined here as Fahrenheit. Changing it to Celsius solved the problem

[image: Fahrenheit]

See it working

[image: See it working]